# RegExp to read txt and filter and only read first match

Tags: javascript, html

I'm reading a txt file that has multiple lines like below.

lastname australia enter

name j.jonhs enter

name j.cause enter

name f.london enter

I'd like to use regexp to read the first line that matches name only and stop reading, can someone help me modify the line below?

```
output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /name/).join("\n").replace("name", "").replace("enter", "");
```

Comment: you like to find first match of 'name' or replace all 'name' and 'enter' with blank

Comment: first match of name and stop. thx

Comment: use re.search('(name)',text) and you will get first match in group(1)

Comment: don't know how to use that. just need to end matching after first match line is found. text varies... just used as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after spiting you got an array. Why don't just target index `0` as-

```
output=output
.split("\n")[0]
.replace("name", "")
.replace("enter", "");
```

### edit after question modification

as you have specific matching on name, you can use `substring` as-

```
const s = `lastname australia enter

name j.jonhs enter

name j.cause enter

name f.london enter`;

let ns = s.split("\n").find((item) => item.substring(0, 4) === 'name')
if(ns){
  // found do something here.
}else{
  // not found
}
```

Comment: sorry... my question was reworded... I really want to find the line that starts with name and stop reading.... it's a long text file and the first line does not start with name.